# Lock Terminal Size

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Is there a way for me to lock the terminal screen size so that it can not be changed? I.e. double clicking the file bar will not maximize the screen, I can not drag the corners to resize it, anything like that until the user specifically unlocks it.

I'll also take any terminal with this feature, not just the default terminal, so long as it can run a python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [devilspie](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie), a non-gui utility that lets you make applications start in specified workplaces, in specified sizes and placements, minimized or maximized and much more based on simple config files.

To install [devilspie [image: Install devilspie]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/devilspie/) you can use Ubuntu Software Center or run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

You can start in terminal devilspie with:

```
devilspie
```

Now I will show how to configure devilspie to lock gnome-terminal size:

- Create a new directory to store your new devilspie-related configuration file:

  ```
  mkdir ~/.devilspie
  ```
- Create a new custom configuration file; for example:

  ```
  gedit ~/.devilspie/gnome-terminal.ds
  ```
- Paste in the following configuration code to your new file:

  ```
  (if (is (application_name) "Terminal")
      (begin
      (undecorate)        
          (geometry "730x450")
          (center)
      )
  )
  ```
- For a full devilspie documentation, see http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie.

After setting it up, you will probably want to run it on start up, so that every window you open will open the way you want it to. For further info as to how to do that, read [AddingProgramToSessionStartup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup).

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie.